# How to run Splash screen then intro slider & then main activity

Tags: java, android

I want to run the activities like Splash screen then intro slider & then main activity. But it runs the splash screen but doesn't run the intro slider after flash screen. How to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.introslider">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="info.androidhive.introslider.Splashscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="info.androidhive.introslider.WelcomeActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.introslider.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

Splash screen.java

```
package info.androidhive.introslider;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIMER = 1000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIMER);
    }
}
```

Comment: set welcome as launcher, then start intro then start main?

Comment: Where the SplashScreen code? did you called startActivity for the second?

Comment: Please add your splash Activity code. And also which is the error you are getting?

Comment: Use the [com.github.paolorotolo.appintro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) package, it is working fine for me, instructions are on the git, but basically you create an activity to the Splash and another to the slide and will call fragments for each one of the slides. [https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro)

Comment: Start the WelcomeActivity from SplashScreen.

Answer (score 2):

**SplashScreen.java** this is you first file

```
    public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
         }
     }, 5000);

    }
}
```

**WelcomeActivity.java**

```
   public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);
        Button btn =findViewById(R.id.welcome_botton);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);       
          }  
       });
    }
}
```

**WelcomeActivity.xml**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/welcome_botton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

          // YOUR MAIN ACTIVITY LOGIC WRITE HERE
        }
    }
```

Refer this Hierarchy and Register all activities in `Manifest.xml` file
these all activity created by me for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Start the WelcomeActivity from SplashScreen.

```
    public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);


        startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class));
        finish();

    }
}
```

Then in your Intro slider activity use sharedpreference to check for first launch. After the first launch your app will move from splash screen to MainActivity.